# Variance-based localized Rademacher complexity for RKHS unit-ball

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, st.statistics, kernels, learning-theory

Let $\mathscr X$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R^d$ (e.g the unit-sphere). Let $K: \mathscr X \times \mathscr X \to \mathbb R$ be a positive kernel function and let $\mathscr H_K$ be the induced RKHS with unit-ball $B_K$. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathscr X$ (e.g the uniform distribution on the unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^d$).

> **Definition.** Given a $r \ge 0$ and "nice" funciton $\phi:L^2(\mu) \to \mathbb R_+$, consider the function class $\mathscr F_{K,\phi, r} := \{f \in B_K \mid \phi(f) \le r\}$, and let $\mathscr R_{K,\phi,r}$ be its Rademacher complexity
> $$
> \mathscr R_{K,\phi,r,n}:= \mathbb E[\sup_{f \in \mathscr F_{K,\phi,r}}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n\varepsilon_i f(x_i)],
> $$
> where $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is an iid sample from $\mu$ and $\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_n$ is an iid Rademacher sample, independent of the $x_i$'s. We note that
> $\mathscr R_{K,\phi,r}$ is also referred to as the *localized* Rademacher complexity of $B_K$ at level $r$, w.r.t $\phi$.

Now, in [(Mendelson 2003, Theorem 2.1)](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume4/mendelson03a/mendelson03a.pdf), it was shown that if $\phi(f):= \|f\|^2_{L^2(\mu)}:=\mathbb E_\mu [f^2]$, then for $\lambda_1 \ge 1/n$, it holds that (for absolute constats $c,C$)

$$
cm(K,r) \le \mathscr R_{K,\phi,r,n} \le Cm(K,r),
$$
where $m(K,r) := (\sum_{i=1}^\infty \min(r,\lambda_i))^{1/2}$ and $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \ldots $ are the eigenvalues of the kernel integral operator induced by $K$, namely the operator $T_K:L^2(\mu) \to L^2(\mu)$ defined by
$$
\begin{split}
f \mapsto T_K f:\mathscr X &\to \mathbb R, \,x\mapsto  \int_{\mathscr X}K(x,y)f(y)d\mu(y).
\end{split}
$$

> **Question.** Can a similar / analagous result be obtained with the choice $\phi(f) := \mathrm{Var}_\mu(f) := \|f-\overline{f}\|_{L^2(\mu)}$, where $\overline{f}$ is the expectation of $f$ w.r.t $\mu$ ?

In general, I'd like to compute good **upper-bounds** on $\mathscr R_{K,\phi,r,n}$ for very general $\phi$, e.g for $\phi(f):=\|f\|_{\mathrm{Lip}}^2$ or even $\phi(f):= \|\nabla f\|_{L^2(\mu)}^2$, when the kernel allows for derivatives.